# Solving a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

Given a sequence
$$x_0=5$$
$$x_{n+1}=x_n*1.03+1$$
how does one find generalized formulae for:

1. $x_n$
2. $\sum_{n=a}^{b}x_n$ for a given pair of $a, b$ where $a{\leq}b$ and $a>0$

Interested in both the closed formulae and (a wonderful cherry on top!) a description on the methodology of solving these kinds of problems.

I can obviously do this recursively, but it feels like this is a common enough problem that has been solved many times over. I'm just unable to find the solution by googling (most likely due to lack of math education - what terms should I be looking for besides the "sequence" and "solve"?)

Comment: Note the [Solving non-homogeneous linear recurrence relations with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_non-homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) section of Wikipedia's "Recurrence relation" article gives an explanation of how to solve general problems like yours.

Comment: Thanks for the link. This is exactly what I was not able to find on my own :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem may be solved by induction on $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The general formula is: $x_{n} = 5*(1.03)^{n} + \sum_{j=1}^{n}{(1.03)^{j-1}}$. Then you have to verify that: $(i)$ The formula holds for $n = 1$. $(ii)$ If the formula holds for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then it holds for $n+1$. Which is not hard to verify. Your second problem is a sum of a geometric progression. Can you conclude from here?

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question completely!

Answer (score 1):

$$x_0=5$$
$$x_{n+1}=1.03x_n+1\tag{1}$$
plug $n+1\to n$
$$x_{n+2}=1.03x_{n+1}+1\tag{2}$$
Subtract $(2)-(1)$
$$x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}=1.03x_{n+1}-1.03x_n$$
rearrange the equation
$$x_{n+2}-2.03x_{n+1}+1.03x_n=0$$
solve the characteristic equation
$$t^2-2.03t+1.03=0\to t_1=1;\;t_2=1.03$$
general solution is
$$x_n=a\cdot 1^n+b\cdot 1.03^n$$

compute $x_1=1.03x_0+1=6.15$

Plug the initial values to get $a,b$

$$a+1.03 b=6.15,a+ b=5\to a=-33.33;\;b=38.33$$
the solution is
$$x_n=38.33\cdot 1.03^n-33.33$$

---

$$\sum _{n=p}^q x_n=\frac{5}{9} \left(60 p-23\cdot 100^{1-p} \cdot103^p+23\cdot 100^{-q} \cdot 103^{q+1}-60 q-60\right)$$